# IcoMoon Font Export Issue

Tags: css, icons, icon-fonts, icomoon

I create a small icon font with IconMoon site. When I import to my website it works fine, but the icon show skew. How I can fix that?

The original icon:

[image]

The showed icon:

[image]

I add this code to all.min.css from Font Awesome:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Pro";
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    src: url(../webfonts/icomoon.eot);
    src: url(../webfonts/icomoon.eot?#iefix) format("embedded-opentype"), url(../webfonts/icomoon.woff) format("woff"), url(../webfonts/icomoon.ttf) format("truetype"), url(../webfonts/icomoon.svg#fontawesome) format("svg")
}

.fac {
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Pro"
}
```

And my code on html:

```
<i class="fac fa-cc-bizum fa-8x" alt="" title=""></i>
```

Comment: Please show us your code [mcve]

Comment: and already is added the class .fa-cc-bizum:before { content: "\e900" } that is icomoon hex location number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I already fixed adding to my .fac class next elements:

```
speak: never;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: normal;
font-variant: normal;
text-transform: none;
line-height: 1;
```